# Error in building a jar file that uses stanford-corenlp as dependency using gradle

Tags: gradle, stanford-nlp

I am writing a very simple program that uses `stanford-corenlp`. I am building my jar using gradle. I have Java 1.8 and `stanford-corenlp` version 3.6.

While building, it generates this error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'StanfordCoreNLPTest'.
>
>   > java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 5.153 secs

Dependency for core nlp is specified in my gradle build file as

```
dependencies {
    compile 'edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.6.0'
    compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.6', classifier: 'models'
}
```

I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Note that version 3.7.0 is available now!  Also here is a link to the build.gradle file that a user contributed that builds Stanford CoreNLP.  https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

This is a gradle build file with which I have successfully built Java applications with stanford corenlp:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.6.0'
    compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.6.0', classifier: 'models'
}
```

Note that:

- CoreNLP 3.6.0 requires Java 8. So I put source and target compatibility to 1.8
- According to the [official instructions](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html) to build with maven, you need 2 include statements for stanford-corenlp and in one of them you put classifier models. The above gradle file does that.

Comment: I noticed I had an issue with path conflictions when I added the 3rd line. "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/demo/corenlp-brat.html'." 
And when I removed it, I needed that line back. Think you can help me with this?